# Pointer size, 32-bit vs 64-bit pointer size inside a method, and the returning value of the method

Tags: c, pointers

I have a method

```
**int** create_object(Object* parent, char* name, int type, int start_block) {
  ...
  return ptr_to_object;
}
```

Inside the function `ptr_to_object` seems to be a 32-bits but then as soon as it gets out of it, it looks like its 64-bits.

Note: I cannot use c99, I know that `intptr_t` is part of c99.

What are your suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `ptr_to_object`, and is there any reason you can't return an actual pointer instead of an integer ? (i.e.g return an Object* )

Comment: Not entirely standard, but often `long` seems to be enough for pointers. Again, not standard.

Comment: `**int**` What type is this supposed to be?

Comment: @Shahbaz It just happens to be so on many contemporary platforms, but it's not standardized in any way. Never use integers to store pointers, if a generic pointer is needed use `void *`.

Comment: If a pointer will fit inside an int, the standard guarantees that everything will work just fine. But If it doesn't fit, then it is undefined behavior and the CPU is free to halt and catch fire.

Comment: How do you know the size?  Did you actually `printf("%u", sizeof(ptr_to_object))` inside and outside of the function?  What architecture are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with pointers, either use a pointer return type, or "hide" it in an int-type defined by the standard to be large enough to support holding a pointer. Such a type *can* exist but is not *guaranteed* to exist (tmk):

> **C99 7.20.1.4** Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> 1. The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
>    **intptr_t**
>
>    The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
>    **uintptr_t**
>
>    **These types are optional**.

The keyword there is *optional*. Chance are likely it is defined on your platform of choice, but for legacy portability you're probably better off either returning a `void *` or declaring a specialized "handle" to a typed or void pointer and returning that.

As always, I'm entirely interested in anyone that is working with a C99-compliant platform that chose *not* to expose some of the features presented as optional in the standard (like this one). If there is anyone out that with a `<stdint.h>` **without** `intptr_t` and/or `uintptr_t` I'm very curious. Please leave a comment if you work with such a toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Like @nos says, if you're dealing with pointers then use a pointer type. Converting them to integers is non-portable and error prone.

If you don't want callers to know it's a pointer (without digging a little anyway), then use `typedef` to create a "handle" type, or something:

```
typedef my_ptr* object_handle;
```

In fact, do this even if your "handle" *really is* an integer. The abstraction will allow you to change it is later without any calling code needing modification.